# How place file with bat command when ran from currenty directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, installation, xcopy

So I am trying to create a bat/exe installer for `regjump`. I am using a bat compiler so I can attach the "regjump.exe" to the installer.exe; so when the installer is ran, it will put `regjump` in the current directory of the installer.exe. I know I can use `xcopy` to place the file but I need help with the first half of the command. What is "local directory\regjump.exe" syntax?

```
cd C:\
xcopy "WHEREVER THE INSTALLER IS RAN FROM\regjump.exe" "C:\Windows\System32" /q /y /r
```

I want the syntax to be able to be ran from anywhere i.e. removable F:

Comment: Remove ``cd C:\`` and use just `xcopy regjump.exe %SystemRoot%\System32 /q /y /r` But the system directory of Windows is not the right place to install an application to.

Comment: regjump is basically a CMD plugin and has to be placed in the System32 folder to work.

Comment: What "bat compiler" are you using?  Does it allow you to specify where the extracted files are put?

Comment: I am using Bat to Exe Converter by F2KO. Its actually fully function free software, if you know how to uncheck boxes during install. http://www.f2ko.de/en/b2e.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You will need to execute as admin to write to "C:\Windows\System32", so this checks for that.

```
openfiles >nul 2>&1 || echo(You must execute this command as Administrator. & pause & goto :eof
set "SourceDir=%CD%
cd C:\
xcopy "%SourceDir%\regjump.exe" "C:\Windows\System32" /q /y /r
```

Comment: I was able to use the line that @Mofi has stated.

`xcopy regjump.exe %SystemRoot%\System32 /q /y /r`